# How can i write an opus stream to a file?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to make a discord bot which can listen to users' command.
I've received the opus stream but, I'm having some issues in saving the file.
After doing this I tried to test the audio and it's saying `The file isn't playable.` Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3Lu.png

````js
const audio = <voiceconnection>.receiver.createStream('User id');
audio.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`audio.opus`);```
````

Comment: Are you sure that the path to the audio file is correct? Is it in the same directory as the code file?

Comment: Yes it is in the same dir @Gh05d